# jQuery - any nice way to easily grant selectbox autocomplete functionality

Tags: jquery, html, select, autocomplete

I am maintaining some legacy code here. Most of the code consists of huge forms, when each form has got many selects. It's very cumbersome to fill the entire form, as you have so many possible values for each select, that finding the one you're looking for takes for ever.

I know that this is where auto complete usually steps in. Does anyone know of any simple way to convert my many select boxes into an auto complete widget using jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this post is old, but I came across it and after a little more research found that [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) has a combobox demo.

Comment: Excellent find, but I have a question. I have a very long list, so when it displays all options, it creates a scrollbar on the web page. Any way to change it to being a scrollbar on the list instead?

Comment: Set the max-height for the autocomplete menu to prevent the menu from growing too large: max-height: 100px; NOTE: doesn't work in IE6

Answer (score 3):

[Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is a great one also (and has other great features available)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, may be [this](https://github.com/laktek/jQuery-Smart-Auto-Complete) helps

bye

Comment: Yup, looks easy. As far as I can see you just need to get all the `.val()` s of the `select` beforehand (no big deal).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these:

- [`jquery-select-autocomplete`](https://github.com/hugoduncan/jquery-select-autocomplete)
- [`vCombobox`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vCombobox)

The first one [sounds promising](https://github.com/hugoduncan/jquery-select-autocomplete#readme):

> jQuery Select Autocomplete lets you
>   turn an HTML  tag into an
>   auto-complete text input box.
>
> You use it like this:
>   `$(select.autocomplete).select-autocomplete();`

Comment: Yes I did, jquery-select-autocomplete doesn't work. I downloaded it and tried running it with no success, and vCombobox doesn't offer the support I am looking for.